# Why do Yongnuo 588 flashes lose flash power as I zoom in?

Tags: canon, flash, yongnuo

I have had two or three of the Yongnuo 568 speedlites and use them with a Canon 24–70mm L lens on a Canon 5D MkIII and a 6D.

The problem I have on both is when I zoom in the power is not correct. If I shoot wide open the flash is perfect in E-TTL but if I zoom to say 50mm it gets darker, and if I zoom to 70mm it gets darker still. Is this a zoom issue? It happens on all three of my Yongnuo flashes and on both cameras. I will be delirious with glee if you can help... in the hope I don't have to revert back to Canon flashes.

All my Yongnuos act the same. Surely this cannot be a fault in all three. I am sure I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What metering mode is selected?

Answer (score 2):

> All my Yongnuo's act the same..surely this cannot be a fault in all 3. I am sure I am doing something wrong.

Well, it kind of is a known issue with Yongnuo flashes when using Canon's *Evaluative Metering*.

Switching main metering to *Center Weighted Average*, *Partial*, or *Spot* metering modes and changing the menu item [Shooting (Red Tab with camera symbol) Tab 1→External Speedlite Control→ETTL II Flash Metering] from *Evaluative* to *Average* usually resolves the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean TTL metering should be set to "average" rather than "evaluative"?  AFAIK, metering pattern has no effect on TTL.

Comment: @inkista I usually change both. It works for me.